# Show and hide div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have about this structure:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <button class="a">Button</button>
    <div class="b" hidden="hidden">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="a">Button</button>
    <div class="b" hidden="hidden">Content</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a').click(function () {
        if ($('.b').is(":visible")) {
            $('.b').hide();
        } else {
            $('.b').show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

How to make that shows only the div on which I clicked

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aahqh80q/).

Comment: `$(this).siblings('.b').toggle();` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aahqh80q/2/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use below code  . check [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aahqh80q/5/)

jquery [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) .

> Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of
>   matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next
>   sibling only if it matches that selector.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    // $('.b').hide();  if you want to hide opened div uncomment this line
     var bOBJ = $(this).next('.b');
    if (bOBJ.is(":visible")) {
        bOBJ.hide();
    } else {
        bOBJ.show();
    }
    //return false;
  });
});
```

Second Option   [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aahqh80q/3/)

Jquery [toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

> Display or hide the matched elements.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $('.a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // $('.b').hide();  if you want to hide opened div uncomment this line  
    $(this).next('.b').toggle();
     //return false;
   });
 });
```

Comment: happy to help you . have added two options in answer you can you as you want :)

Answer (score 2):

For finding closest `div.b` use [jQuey.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/). Instead of using `.show()` and `.hide()` use [jQuery.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
$(function() {
    $('.a').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.b').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button class="a">Button</button>
    <div class="b" hidden="hidden">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="a">Button</button>
    <div class="b" hidden="hidden">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

***PLEASE CHECK***

```js
 $('.a').click(function () {
        
            $('.b').hide();
        $(this).siblings('.b').show();
       
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button class="a">Button</button>
    <div class="b" hidden="hidden">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="a">Button</button>
    <div class="b" hidden="hidden">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though _please check_ is definitely much worse than explanation of your idea, your code works in different way than code in most other answers. Who knows: maybe it is what is really required.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a').click(function () {
        var parent =$(this).parent();
        var content =parent.find(".b").first();

        if ($(content).is(":visible")) {
            $(content).hide();
        } else {
            $(content).show();
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no need in `$()` in `$(content)`. `content.hide();` will work just fine. And once again: what about `.toggle()`?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```js
$('.a').click(function(){
$(this).next('.b').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <button class="a">Button</button>
    <div class="b" hidden="hidden">Content</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <button class="a">Button</button>
    <div class="b" hidden="hidden">Content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and easy solution. Please check here: sfiddle.net/webyourway/aahqh80q/9/

The using of html attribute called 'hidden' is really rare. I've never used it before honestly. I guess the main reason of rare use is that semantically it should be used to hide the element regardless presentation. In your case it seems that it is better to use CSS display:none.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a').click(function () {
        $('.b').hide();
        $(this).next('.b').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: My fault. I've never used this attribute before. Good to know the use case for using it however. I reckon that one from the Q is not a best way to use it. 
I will correct my post. Also you are 100% right about the naming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .toggle() to show and hide alternative.
try to this.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.a').click(function () {
   $(this).next('.b').toggle(1000);
 });
});
```